# SwiftUI change text size for macOS

Tags: swift, swift5

Using SwiftUI for a small all and I noticed that the font size is very small on macOS

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List(fetch.Novitadss) { Novitads in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        // 3.
                        Text(Novitads.title)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .fontWeight(.regular)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: Novitads.link)!)
                            }
                    }
                }
```

I would like to add a condition to change the .font(.headline) if os is macOS
so I tried

```
                         #if os(iOS)
                            .font(.headline)
                        #elseif os(macOS)
                               .font(.title)
                        #endif
```

but I get "Unexpected platform condition (expected 'os', 'arch', or 'swift')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following helper extension

```
extension Text {
    func platformFont() -> Text {
#if canImport(AppKit) || targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        return self.font(.title)
#elseif canImport(UIKit)
         return self.font(.headline)
#else
        return self
#endif
    }
}
```

and usage

```
Text(Novitads.title)
   .platformFont()
```

**Update:** Added demo. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
            Text("Hello World!").platformFont()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to preferring `canImport` over `os`?

Comment: @asperi thanks for the reply but for me not to die stupid..why is #if os(iOS) not working ?

Comment: @Sweeper `canImport` is better than `os` because your test is based on functionality rather than operating system. If UIKit becomes available for macOS, you don't have to change your code to use it.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for macOS. It does for iOS but for macOS the font size is not applied. I also tried to change it to #elseif canImport(AppKit)  return self.font(.system(size: 60)) but the font size remains unchanged on macOS

Comment: @devnull, see updated with test worked demo, so I assume the issue in some different code.

Comment: @Asperi I carefully used the same code the only thing different is that my title is inside a list. Could be that for lists it doesn't work ?

Comment: @devnull, hmm... just put those two Text from demo into List, instead of VStack, and List into NavigationView, and all works - each font applied correctly. ... Just got a mind, don't you run it on mac/Catalyst? Because I'm about native macOS App.

Comment: @Asperi sorry to bother again but I would love to know what's wrong :)  see code  with screenshot https://gist.github.com/gurugeek/28e5e1a775e01554bd783dd678a068d6 did I do something wrong? resizing works fine on iOS... Xcode 11.4.1 running on Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: found a solution      #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst) anything else won't work

Comment: @devnull, I asked you above about Catalyst ;) mac/Catalyst is not macOS target, it is iOS simulation in macOS, so there is no AppKit there, but UIKit, so condition did not work for you. Just in case.

Comment: @Asperi thanks again so if I build the app for distribution I shouldn't use catalist but AppKit?

Comment: @devnull, it is better to keep both, I updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289969/swiftui-change-text-size-for-macos/61290171#comment108429855_61290171), you asked why your code did not work, which I will explain in my answer.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID538), a conditional compilation block has the following syntax:

[image]

Notice that it says "statements" inside the block. `.font(.headline)` is not a statement, so it is illegal to put that there. This is also evident in the formal grammar notation further down the page:

[image]

In addition, in the "Note" block just above the formal grammar:

> Each statement in the body of a conditional compilation block is parsed even if it’s not compiled. However, there is an exception if the compilation condition includes a `swift()` platform condition.

This explains why your `#elseif` block has the error as well.

In other words, `#if` statements are *not* your C++ preprocessor directives :)

Therefore, to fix the problem, you must put a *whole statement* in those blocks. One (dumb) way to fix this would be:

```
 #if os(iOS)
Text(Novitads.title)
    .font(.headline)
    .fontWeight(.regular)
    .onTapGesture {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: Novitads.link)!)
    }
#elseif os(macOS)
Text(Novitads.title)
    .font(.title)
    .fontWeight(.regular)
    .onTapGesture {
        // UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: Novitads.link)!)
        // you would use this on macOS to open URLs, right?
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: Novitads.link)!)
    }
#endif
```

Of course, Asperi's solution of extracting a `platformFont` method is a *lot* better.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/catalyst/how-to-detect-your-ios-app-is-running-on-macos-catalyst)
It should be like this:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
return self.font(.largeTitle)
#elseif os(iOS)
return self.font(.system(size: 10))
#else
return self
#endif
```